# Can "fait + noun" be done without a determiner for the noun?

Tags: grammaire, déterminants

> Le cuir **fait appel** à tous mes sens et spécialement à l'odorat.

(My translation attempt: The leather "*made call*" to all my senses and especially to the sense of smell).

When I see "fait appel", I first wonder if the grammar being used is causative faire. But wordreference tells me that [appel](http://www.wordreference.com/fren/appel?s=fait%20appel) is only a noun, never an infinitive verb or a conjugated verb.  "[faire](http://www.wordreference.com/fren/faire)" in wordreference, indeed is a transitive verb (that is, a verb that takes a direct object), but all of the examples it gives shows that the direct object has a determiner; for example:

> - Nous avons fait ***ces*** 200 km en 2 heures.
> - Allez, je vous fais ***ce*** lot de livres à 5 €.
> - Avec des légumes, je fais ***un*** potage.

So I thought that perhaps "faire appel" is an expression, but wordreference turns up nothing.

Questions:
1) What is happening with there no being determiner for "appel", in "faire appel"? Is this something that a reference (eg, a dictionary) could clarify for me?

Comment: @Améraldor: can you give me an example of using Wikitionnaire for this example? (jlliagre's link to the TLF gives me some idea of how to use TLF when i suspect something is a set expression)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Faire appel* is indeed a set expression:

[TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/appel)

> 4. Lang. cour. **Faire appel à qqn** ou à **qqc**. En vue d'une action.
>      ...
>      b) [Le compl. est inanimé ou abstr.] Se servir de quelque chose.
>      − [Chose concr.] :
>
>    33. Une autre solution consiste à **faire appel à** *un dispositif mécanique* basé sur le changement d'amplification de la timonerie suivant que l'on veut freiner la tare seule ou la tare et la charge. M. Bailleul, *Notions de matériel roulant des ch. de fer*, 1951, p. 140.

Also in the *Wiktionnaire*:

https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/faire_appel

Comment: And the translation: *"**to call on** someone / something"*